# A word or phrase for the value of something to an outlaw

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

tldr: what's a noun/phrase for 'value to a nefarious agent'?

Specific example: Teslas are the least likely car to be stolen while the Accord, at 2/3 of the cost, gets stolen all the time. There are similar examples of the difference between "value" and "value to a thief".

Fence-able seems contrived and ignores some of the other value of stolen goods, for example: 'worthless to most' family photos could be held ransom.

Is there a synonym for value that applies specifically to outlaws?

Comment: I think you mean the value to an outlaw and not of an outlaw......

Comment: Maybe you could use ***street value***

Comment: Since it sounds like there aren't great word/phrases for this in English, can we open it up to other languages for linguistic importation?

Comment: That would depend on the outlaw. "The goods" comes to mind, a slang term.

Answer (score 0):

The term for this (in any market, including the black market) is **liquidity**:

> Financial liquidity refers to how easily assets can be converted into cash. Assets like stocks and bonds are very liquid since they can be converted to cash within days. However, large assets such as property, plant, and equipment are not as easily converted to cash. — [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/basics/07/liquidity.asp)

Here are examples involving stolen goods:

> Unfortunately, paying ransoms for art increases its liquidity and therefore makes it a more attractive target. — [Crimes Involving Art](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1143976)

> If we examine various market indicators, we can see how the black markets have increased efficiency. The most obvious indicators to track are the price of the final output and the “liquidity” or the volume of trading that occurs. The price at which a fully qualified identity is sold is a good proxy for the cost of acquisition of that identity and the overall efficiency of the market. — [The black market for identity theft](https://www.networkworld.com/article/2285962/the-black-market-for-identity-theft.html)

Comment: liquidity is great for goods! not so great for identities or photo albums

Comment: @user121330 Why not? (I also added an example about identity theft.)

Comment: It's growing on me. I can imagine liquid assets that are impossible to fence (a check, for example) and easily fenced objects which are otherwise illiquid (stolen musical instruments) though. Describing my photo album as a liquid asset, or one with high liquidity makes very little sense unless I provide added context which is what I originally sought - a word that emphasizes the the value to a thief. Liquidity merely describes the ease of converting an asset to cash which is just part of the value to a thief

Comment: Hmmm... *liquidity* still requires reference to a thief.